# ASP.NET Core Webroot - html file won't load properly, but will on local drive

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Was having a problem in a view, and drilled down to do this test:

Same HTML file on local drive, and in Webroot.  Local drive, loads in browser fine, scripts work.  Launch from Webroot and scripts won't work.  Source of file path in Webroot is there and correct.  I have no other problems loading files from Webroot so I am thinking it could be a problem with the google call.

These are the two files that I am having problems with running:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/custom/_googlemap_init.js"></script>
```

Opening sources in chrome show they are being called:
[image]

Comment: Open the dev console in your browser and give us some information about the responses you're receiving for these requests.

Comment: hopefully that helps - don't get it though.  Wont display map on webpage, but does fine when not doing it from VS in Webroot.

Answer (score 0):

Try a leading forward slash in the js:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="/js/custom/_googlemap_init.js"></script>
```